# Is there a way to easily sum a few columns together, but only if the text next to them matches a dropdown selection

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, filtering

I've been trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong here when i'm doing the sumif formula's in b2,c2,d2
I have a lot going on, I realize. The data we are looking at, is between L5:U21

I have a query in a5 that pulls from l5:U that pairs any data in n5:n,p5:p,r5:r,t5:t to the selected data in the dropdown in a2. This part is working correctly for what I need.

B2 I am trying to extract from the top 3 options in the range b5:J that match a2, and add them together. Ultimately I'd like to do this if they do not have "Left" or "Right" in the J column as well.
To achieve this I pulled the data from b5:I into a sortn function seen in y5.

`=SORTN(B5:I,3,,B5:B,false,D5:D,false,F5:F,false,H5:H,false)`

and then my SUMIF function is as follows: `=SUMIF(Z5:AF,A2,Y5:AE)`

C2 is similar to B2, but I only data that matches the selection in a2, but also have "Left" in the J column.

I tried to achieve this with a similar SUMIF function i'm using in b2, but it seems to only pull the left most cell's data in the range given, not the matching column's data. So lets say if e9 = example1, it doesn't then grab the matching 2 in d9, it grabs whatever is in b9 only, and adds that. Which right now, it adds them all. I want to ultimately only pull the top 1, but I cannot even get it working correctly with all of them.
`=SUMIF(J5:J,"Left",B5:H)`

D2 is the same as C2, but "Right" in the J column.

This is my example / testing document I created to get a closer look at what's going on, if what i'm explaining isn't making a ton of sense.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eZ7_yOrkoy_PCgcn_YxscPnDCvLXWK48JW-S7DqEgdQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just to clarify your main issue, it is on function on cell `B2` & you basically want to sum up the top 3 from columns **#1**,**#2**,**#3**,**#4** in descending order that matches whatever you select on cell `A2` **AND** that doesn't contain `Right` or `Left` adjacent on column `J` as seen here on this sample [visualized step-by-step logic](https://imgur.com/a/9buoFsk). Correct?

Comment: Correct, ultimately that's is the end goal for B2. I just hadn't gotten that far, since it was a similar problem to what I was having with C2 and D2's function of narrowing them down depending on either "Right" or "Left"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in `C2`

```
=QUERY({{B5:C;D5:E;F5:G},{J5:J;J5:J;J5:J}},
         "select sum(Col1) where Col2='"&A2&"' and Col3='Left'
          label sum(Col1) '' ",0)
```

For cell `D2` all you need to do is use `Col3='Right'`

```
=QUERY({{B5:C;D5:E;F5:G},{J5:J;J5:J;J5:J}},
         "select sum(Col1) where Col2='"&A2&"' and Col3='Right'
          label sum(Col1) '' ",0)
```

In case you want to add more ranges like columns `H-I` you would adjust your formula like:

```
{{B5:C;D5:E;F5:G;H5:I},{J5:J;J5:J;J5:J;J5:J}}
```

*(**Do adjust** the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Lovely. This actually worked out perfectly. I adjusted it a little to do MAX instead of SUM because I realized I actually only wanted the top option instead of the sum of all of them. I wish I could mark both answers as a checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

I was experimenting earlier with `SUMIFS` & `QUERY` formulas to no success, as I also have a limited knowledge when it comes to implementing advanced Google Sheet formulas in a complex scenario. What I can suggest you try is by using a ***Custom Function*** formula in **Google Sheet** made possible by *Google Apps Script* that's integrated to the Google Sheet service.

This custom formula function will filter the range that does not contain `Left` or `Right` in column `J` based on the selected drop-down data, and then it returns the top 3 results in descending order.

### The Custom formula Script named as `CUSTOM_FUNC`

```
/**
 * Filters data in descending order from a range that doesn't contain any Left & Right based on selection in a cell dropdown selection & return the sum of the top 3 result.
 *
 * @param {B5:J21,A2}  reference  The range to be used.
 * @returns                       The range and the cell reference to used in filtereing the data.
 * @customfunction
 */
function CUSTOM_FUNC(data,dropdown_selection) {
  /**Filter data that do not contain Left or Right on column J */
  var lvl1 = data.map(x => {return x.toString().includes('Left') || x.toString().includes('Right') ? null : x }).filter(y => y)
  /**Further filter lvl1 that matches the drop down selection*/
  var res = lvl1.map(d => {
    return d.map((find, index) => {return find == dropdown_selection ? d[index-1] : null}).filter(z => z)
  });
  /**Return the top 3 result in descending order */
  return res.sort().reverse().slice(0, 3);
}
```

***The parameters of this customer formula would be:***

```
=CUSTOM_FUNC(data,dropdown_selection)
```

- `data`

The sheet range (e.g. `B5:J21`) where the data you'd like to be processed resides.

- `dropdown_selection`

The cell reference of the drop-down selection on your spreadsheet file.

> **To add this script in your spreadsheet file**, copy and paste the script as a **bound script** in your Spreadsheet file by following [this official guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#google_sheets_or_docs)

### Demonstration

- You can use the ***custom function*** formula named `CUSTOM_FUNC` similarly to how you use another Google Sheet formula on a cell, like this `=SUM(CUSTOM_FUNC(B5:J21,A2))`

> [image]

Comment: Hmm, that does seem to solve that problem for sure. It does have a slight loading time now, but that's not the end of the world. What would I need to update in the script if I wanted it to add up the ones that do say LEFT, or RIGHT respectively?

Comment: You can update the conditions inside of the variable `lvl1`. E.g. if you would like to add new words in it, it should look like this `var lvl1 = data.map(x => {return x.toString().includes('Left') || x.toString().includes('Right') || x.toString().includes('NEW_WORD') ? null : x }).filter(y => y)`. Just add `||` (**Or** sign) in between.

Comment: Also, if we answered your question, you may want to click the accept/up-vote button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved Or at least find something that they can start with. That way, they'll be easily recommended to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah that works for adding more. I'm just trying to utilize a similar script to utilize for ```C2``` and ```D2``` where I want the top option from the columns if J says LEFT and matches the dropdown for example for ```C2```

Comment: More or less I'm trying to have ```C3``` and ```D3``` be like ```=IF(J5:J="Left",LARGE(B5:I,1),"")``` , but also still matching the value in a2, since I won't need to SUM like before and I only need the top option. If that make sense.